# How to rewrite long query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I have the following 2 tables:

```
items:
 id int primary key
 bla text

events:
 id_items int
 num int
 when timestamp without time zone
 ble text
 composite primary key: id_items, num
```

and want to select to each item the most recent event (the newest 'when').
I wrote an request, but I don't know if it could be written more efficiently.
<del>Also on PostgreSQL there is a issue with comparing Timestamp objects:
2010-05-08T10:00:00.123 == 2010-05-08T10:00:00.321
so I select with 'MAX(num)'</del>
Any thoughts how to make it better? Thanks.

```
SELECT i.*, ea.* FROM items AS i JOIN
( SELECT t.s AS t_s, t.c AS t_c, max(e.num) AS o FROM events AS e JOIN
( SELECT DISTINCT id_item AS s, MAX(when) AS c FROM events GROUP BY s ORDER BY c ) AS t
ON t.s = e.id_item AND e.when = t.c GROUP BY t.s, t.c ) AS tt
ON tt.t_s = i.id JOIN events AS ea ON ea.id_item = tt.t_s AND ea.cas = tt.t_c AND ea.num = tt.o;
```

**EDIT**: had bad data, sorry, my bad, however thanks for finding better SQL query

Comment: А note: there's no DATETIME type in Postgres, you probably mean TIMESTAMP.

Comment: good point :)
is should be "timestamp without time zone"
will edit it

Comment: what's the "issue with comparing timestamp objects"?

Comment: @araqnid
2010-05-08T10:00:00.123 == 2010-05-08T10:00:00.321 (in PostgreSQL)

Comment: @pingi : "select '2010-05-08T10:00:00.123'::timestamp = '2010-05-08T10:00:00.321'::timestamp " gives false, as it should. What is the issue?

Comment: @araqnid: my bad, had some duplicates in data, next time i check the input ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  (i).*, (e).*
FROM    (
        SELECT  i,
                (
                SELECT  e
                FROM    events e
                WHERE   e.id_items = i.id
                ORDER BY
                        when DESC
                LIMIT 1
                ) e
        FROM    items i
        ) q
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 8.4:

```
select * from (
  select item.*, event.*,
         row_number() over(partition by item.id order by event."when" desc) as row_number
  from items item
       join events event on event.id_items = item.id
) x where row_number = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of joins, I prefer the [**DISTINCT ON**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/queries-select-lists.html) syntax ([example](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/4-Using-Distinct-ON-to-return-newest-order-for-each-customer.html)).
It's a Postgresql extension (not SQL standard syntax), but it comes *very* handy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (it.id) 
it.*, ev.*
FROM items it, events ev
WHERE ev.id_items = it.id
ORDER by it.id, ev.when DESC;
```

You can't beat that, on terms of simplicity and readability.

That query assumes that every item has at least one event. If not, and if you want all
events, you'll need an outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (it.id) 
it.*, ev.*
FROM items it LEFT JOIN events ev
ON ev.id_items = it.id
ORDER BY it.id, ev.when DESC;
```

BTW: There is no *"timestamp issue"* in Postgresql, perhaps you should change the title.